# Why is the change in resistance not directly proportional to the change in temperature?

Tags: condensed-matter, temperature, electric-current, electrical-resistance

Change of resistance with respect to temperature is defined as 
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}R}{R}=k\mathrm{d}T$$
where $k$ is a proportionality constant, $R$ the resistance, $T$ the temperature and $\mathrm{d}R$ is change in resistance.

Why it is $\mathrm{d}R$ not directly defined as proportional to $\mathrm{d}T$?

Comment: 1. Have a look at my edit. Please do not post formulae as plain text, but use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/143136) instead. 2. It is not clear to me why you claim that this is a *definition* of $\mathrm{d}R$ rather than a non-trivial physical law. To me, the *definition* of $\mathrm{d}R$ would simply be as the change of/differential of $R$.

Comment: Do you mean electrical resistance? Which material? Can you provide a reference where you obtained this formula? How did the author arrive at it?

Answer (score 2):

As stated: 
$$\frac{dR}{R} = kdT,$$

this means that

$$dR \propto R dT.$$

Integrating this gives:

$$T = \int dT \propto \int \frac{dR}{R},$$

this gives $kT = \ln(R) - \ln(R_0)$ or $R = R_0e^{kT}$.

If we were to write $dR \propto dT$ then we find:

$$R = kT +R_0,$$

for some constant $k$.

**In an experiment one can measure $(T,R)$-diagram and find that it fits the first option since physics is of course about explaining the real world by doing experiments!**

Comment: In my opinion, the OP hasn't considered that physics equations ultimately depend on experiments.  If you are going to develop a mathematical model of a real phenomenon, the experimental results highly constrain the form of the mathematical equation that can be used.

Comment: In your formula $T=ln(R) ....$ can't be right, it should be $kT=ln(R) ...$

Answer (score 0):

Change in resistance doesn't only depend on temperature change.

dR depends on the following three factors,,

1) Directly proportional to rise in temperature.

2)Directly proportional to initial resistance.

3) Depends upon nature of conductor.

By (1) & (2) we can write

$dR=R_0k*dT$

or

$dR/R=k*dT$

Because if initially the resistance is high,the temperature increase will increase more resistance relatively

Answer (score 0):

The proper equations are the following. The first is for dependence of the materials resistivity on temperature. The second is for the change in resistance of the finished resistor (composed of the material).

$$ρ=ρ_{0}[1+α(T-T_{0})]$$

$$R=R_{0}[1+α(T-T_{0})]$$

Where $ρ_{0}$ is the resistivity at $T_0$, $R_{0}$ is the resistance at $T_{0}$ and $α$ is the temperature coefficient.

Since $dR$ is $R-R_{0}$ then the second equation becomes.

$$R-R_{0}=R_{0}α(T-T_{0})$$

Which I think is what you are trying to say.

Hope this helps.